# how to open a file in windows, from Pharo environment?

Tags: operating-system, pharo

I'm building something in Smalltalk [pharo](/questions/tagged/pharo) and I need to open files in the underlying OS (Windows 10). Specifically, I need to open certain types of files with the registered Windows app (.pdf, .wav, etc.), as well as the explorer.
I'm lost - can't find the way to do it or the classes that deal with it. Can you give me a clue?

I loaded [Pharo-OS-Windows](https://github.com/astares/Pharo-OS-Windows). It seems not to work in my computer.
Things like `WinShell shellOpen: 'c:\pharo.pdf'` produce no visible result.

I tried to load OSProcess, but it seems to be outdated (it works with a deprecated file system, as far as I could understand)

PS: please take into account that I'm a beginner and an amateur.

Comment: When the example give [here](https://github.com/astares/Pharo-OS-Windows#open-a-document) is not working, I would create new issue here: https://github.com/astares/Pharo-OS-Windows/issues

Answer (score 0):

if you still have not for that working try:
`OSWSWinProcess new shellCommand: 'c:\pharo.pdf'`.
download OSWinSubprocess from:
https://github.com/pharo-contributions/OSWinSubprocess